# Cómo corregir este error en la consulta Oracle?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Buen día.

Estoy creando tablas de base de datos con Oracle a través de SQL Developer sobre una empresa. Tengo muy poca experiencia y práctica con esta herramienta. He investigado y creé las tablas pero al momento de ejecutar se generan muchos errores. Son 18 tablas en total, en donde las llaves primarias y foráneas.

He aquí una de las tablas y su correspondiente error:

```
create table especie
(
cod_especie integer constraint especie_pk primary key,
nro_especie varchar(30),
qt_especieTallaMinima integer,
qt_cantidadMaxCaptura integer,
constraint cod_lugarPescafk foreign key(cod_LugarPesca) references LugarPesca(cod_LugarPesca),
constraint cod_pezfk foreign key(cod_pez) references pez(cod_pez),
constraint cod_veda foreign key(cod_veda) references veda(cod_veda)
)
```

```
Informe de error -
ORA-00904: "COD_LUGARPESCA": identificador no válido
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

No entiendo a qué se refiere con "identificador no válido". Pienso que tal vez me equivoqué al escribir las sentencias.

Agradecería vuestra orientación.

Comment: Como consejo para la vida: siempre que encuentres un ORA-XXXXX, búscalo que cada uno tiene un montón de detalles detrás.

Answer (score 4):

El error lo marca por que no hay una columna con ese nombre en la tabla `especie`

```
foreign key(cod_LugarPesca)
```

Para referenciar una llave foranea debe existir un campo con el mismo tipo de dato (el nombre puede ser diferente) que la llave primaria de la tabla a la cual se hace referencia, aca un ejemplo:

```
create table table1(
  idTable1 int not null,
  campo varchar2(16) not null,
  constraint pk_tabla1 primary key (idTabla1)
);

create table table2(
  idTable2 int not null,
  idTable1OtroNombre int not null,
  campoT2 varchar2(16),
  constraint pk_table2 primary key (idTable2),
  constraint fk_tabl1_table2 foreign key(idTable1OtroNombre) references Table1(idTable1)
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Te haría las siguientes observaciones:

- Revisando la sintaxis<sup>1</sup> de Oracle y parece ser que no acepta el uso de mayúsculas en la declaración de `CONSTRAINTS`
- Declara de tipo **`integer`** los nombres de las columnas que se encargarán de trabajar como llaves foráneas
- Cuando le pasas un valor a la función a la función **`FOREIGN KEY()`** este debería se el nombre de la columna que va a servir como llave foránea y unión con la tabla que tiene la llave principal, *que si revisas no existe en tu tabla*, entonces necesitas agregar las columnas:

  - `cod_pez`
  - `cod_lugarpesca`
  - `cod_veda`
- Idealmente agrega al final de la sintaxis de tu tabla la declaración del motor que se empleará que en este caso es: **`INNODB`**

**Ejemplo**

```
create table especie
(
    cod_especie integer constraint especie_pk primary key,
    nro_especie varchar(30),
    qt_especieTallaMinima integer,
    qt_cantidadMaxCaptura integer,
    cod_lugarpesca integer,
    cod_pez integer,
    cod_veda integer,
    constraint cod_lugarpescafk foreign key(cod_lugarpesca) references LugarPesca(cod_LugarPesca),
    constraint cod_pezfk foreign key(cod_pez) references pez(cod_pez),
    constraint cod_veda foreign key(cod_veda) references veda(cod_veda)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

**Referencias**

- <sup>1</sup>[docs Referencia](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.6-en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)